# Directionally flip tiles with CSS3 based on mouseenter direction while also using a toggle for default flip

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

So I have a grid of tiles.

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F5SbD/1/)

I'm trying to flip them based on the mouseenter direction (eg: if the mouse enters from the bottom, the tile flips upwards, if the mouse enters from the left the tile flips right). The problem arises as you need to rotate the back of the tiles to the correct orientation before transforming them in order to get the rotation in the correct direction.

The toggle is supposed to flip all the tiles into position two whereupon they can be rotated in reverse on hover.

If you look at my script I've added classes on mouseenter to give me a hook for my direction. I've tried with @keyframes to try to set the alignment for the tiles before they rotate and I couldn't get the tiles to re-rotate on mouseout. I've also used a method which performs the rotation of the back of the tile to the correct orientation and then fires the animation 10ms after. This is seem a little buggy though.

Any other suggestions I might have missed?

```
<a href="#" class="toggle">Toggle</a>
<div class="grid">
    <div class="tile posone">
        <div class="front"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x175/00baff/ffffff" height="175" height="250" /></div>
        <div class="back"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x175/ffa800/ffffff" height="175" height="250" /></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

flip = { 
    init: function(){
        $('.toggle').on('click', flip.toggle);
        $('.tile').on('hover', flip.hover);
    },

    toggle: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.tile').each(function(i, elm) {
                setTimeout(function(){
            flip.autoFlip($(elm));
        }, i*40);
        });
    },

    hover: function(e){
        if (e.type === 'mouseenter'){
            var dir = flip.getDir($(this), { x:e.pageX, y:e.pageY });
        }
        flip.flipOver($(this), e.type, dir);
    },

    flipOver: function($elm, type, dir){

            switch (dir) {
                case 0 :
                    $elm.addClass('top');   
                break;
                case 1 :
                    $elm.addClass('right'); 
                break;
                case 2 :
                    $elm.addClass('bottom');    
                break;
                case 3 :
                    $elm.addClass('left');  
                break;
                default :
                    $elm.removeClass('top right bottom left');
            }

            $elm.toggleClass('posone postwo');

    },

    autoFlip: function($elm){
        $elm.toggleClass('posone postwo');
    },

    getDir: function($elm, coord){
        var w = $elm.width(),
            h = $elm.height(),
            x = ( coord.x - $elm.offset().left - ( w/2 )) * ( w > h ? ( h/w ) : 1 ),
            y = ( coord.y - $elm.offset().top  - ( h/2 )) * ( h > w ? ( w/h ) : 1 ),
            direction = Math.round( ( ( ( Math.atan2(y, x) * (180 / Math.PI) ) + 180 ) / 90 ) + 3 )  % 4;
        return direction;
    }

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    flip.init();
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow jsFiddle won't load for me now, but I'd say don't rotate `.front` and `.back`, rotate `.tile` on hover. And have `.back` rotated at 180 degrees (`rotateY` when hovering from the left, `rotateX` when hovering from the right) with no transition on it.

Comment: I think I've over complicated this, I'm going to try it now!

Comment: Ok so you'd think if you positioned two images absolutely, top:0, left:0; within a div so they were stacked on top of each other and you then flipped that div you'd see the bottom image reversed? You don't... you only see the top image back-to-front  :(

Comment: Ok following on from this. It won't work anyway even if it did show the back tile because if you initially had the back-face flipped on the X axis and then your tile flip was on the Y axis you'd end up with your text upside down on the back-face tile when it was facing the front.

Comment: But you change that without a transition when you make the tile flip. You only have a transition on the rotate transform of the tile, not on that of the back face as well.

Comment: if you're interested and you can get jsfiddle to work here's my [final solution](http://jsfiddle.net/xKnLe/). Thanks for your help but as far as I could see there was no way to flip the parent and get the back to actually show when it becomes the front.